# read tags when buildir is not srcdir

Tags: vim, autotools, ctags

I' using an autotools project with source on

```
~/jhbuild/checkout/<project>
```

and compilation on

```
~/.cache/jhbuild/build/<project>
```

inside `~/.cache/jhbuild/build/<project>` I can make

```
$ make ctags
```

and tags are generated correctly for `~/jhbuild/checkout/<project>`

but I would like to open vim on `~/jhbuild/checkout/<project>` to be able to navigate files directly (not only with tag definitions). Is there a way to instruct vim to search tags recursively on cache dir?

On `~/jhbuild/checkout/<project>` I can make `ctags -R *` and mostly have the same (with a non recursive tag file) Is there any benefit in use autotools ctags rule? I see CTAGS_DEPENDECIES CTAGS_FLAGS CTAGS_ARGS but never see anyone using it

Comment: See `:help 'tags'`.